# Адаптация шапки и всё её содержимое

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая проблема, при сужении сайта изображение уменьшается, то сама высота блока не изменяется и получается пустое место, как сделать, что бы блок тоже уменьшался и нижний блок в жёлтом фоне нормально подстраивался, прописать медиазапросы, для каждого пикселя?

```css
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
}

body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.main-header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 550px;
 background: url(http://i94.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0731/74/a0ee171306bbf3d3f956177696aea374.jpg) no-repeat ;
 background-size:100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
.inner-header {
 border: 1px solid;
 max-width: 1280px;
 height: 550px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

.logo {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid;
}
.discription {
 float: right;
 border: 1px solid;
}

.btn-chooce {
 width: 300px;
 text-align: center;
 background: yellow;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left:50%;
 right:50%;
 margin-left:-150px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Сайт</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class="main-header">
   <div class="inner-header">
    <div class="logo clearfix">Логотип</div>
    <div class="discription">
     <p>Описание сайта</p>
     <p>текст текст текст текст текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-chooce">Кнопка, по которой надо нажать</div>
   </div>
  </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может достаточно будет прописать для блока с картинкой на заднем фоне background-size: cover;. Если я конечно правильно понял суть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Задай высоту блоков не в пикселях, а в vw (для этого примера подойдёт 43vw), тогда высота блока будет изменяться пропорционально изменению ширины экрана.